# How to avoid push exist route in flutter? Or any way to replace exist route?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm using getx on flutter

And I faced a problem when using Get.toNamed

For example, there are page A, B, C

Page C has a button that can go to Page A. And page A has a scrollController

When I move like A -> B -> C -> A

Error says scrollController has attatched to multiple scroll view.

It seems like logic(controller) is not duplicated so there is only one controller  with 2 view

And I don't want seperated logic

Is there any way to Avoid this error?

What I want to do is A -> B -> C and tapped button to go Page A then go to A while maintaining A -> B -> C stacks

Thanks

Comment: Is your controller static by any chance?

Comment: @RăzvanPuiu For more Information. Page A is kinda detail page, so controller is not static all time. It has tag that Identify controller. 

This problem occured when user enter Page A with product apple(route A/apple) then go to Page C that has button to go Page A with product apple... so controller(tag: apple) inits only once and has 2 different view.

if your 'controller static' means different from my comments. please let me know
Thanks